# Moving WordPress to another domain

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been making a website for a friend of mine.

http://freelanceaccounting.co.za

It's for a school. Now I want to move the entire WordPress site to his domain.

I was going to follow this guide: (also unless I am mistaken this guide says I don't need to install WordPress on the new domain, the install.bak that the plugin creates. will install it for me???)

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-wordpress-to-a-new-domain-without-losing-seo/

But I wanted to know if the SO community knew a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your domain have a host? if yes download your existing file and upload it to host.

https://ph.godaddy.com/help/upload-files-3239

also dont forget to configure your database in host..

Comment: my exising wordpress theme file?

Comment: all files not only the theme.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest way drop a mail or call to hostiong provider say i want to change domain name and set DNS server to new domain and change DNS to old domain.

and check... :)